# Flowering shrub ID

Tags: identification

I'd like to know what this striking bush is called. I saw it in San Francisco.

[image: bush with red flowers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a poinsettia, Euphorbia pulcherrima.

Comment: I agree, Lorel.  Haven't seen too many of these outside the nurseries at Christmas...growing in the landscape.

Comment: Thanks, Lorel! I'd never recognized one out of the pot before.